# Parsing objects in Json array as a dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsarray

So I have JSON data that is formatted as a list of dictionaries, and I have it stored as an NSArray Object, but I'm unsure how to convert each entry into a dictionary object when it is currently AnyObject

The AnyObject data is already formatted like a JSON dictionary

Here is the code I used to create the Array

```
func startConnection(){
    let urlPath: String = "http://api.mtgdb.info/search/omni"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()




}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray
    for var i = 0; i<jsonResult.count; ++i{
       ...

    }

}
```

Comment: So you say you have these dictionaries stored in an NSArray.  Are they NSStrings in the array?  Or are they some other sort of object, like an NSDictionary?

Comment: I edited my post with the code used to create the NSArray

Comment: The JSON returned by that URL is an array of dictionaries, so all you need to do is use `as! NSDictionary` when you access the outer array elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this sample code to solve your problem.
First of all run this "http://api.mtgdb.info/search/omni" URL in web browser and copy response then paste into "http://jsonlint.com", response is valid and I get array of 8 dictionaries, Like id: 37113, 39932, 83737, 106426, 228247, 288937, 382286, 386302 -- 8 data.

In Objective C, It works perfect and I get same result as web browser.
But in Swift, It behave weird, Can't parse whole respose, get only half dictionary as object of array. Only get this much part of response,

`Printing description of jsonResult:
(
        {
        artist = "Arnie Swekel";
        cardSetId = JUD;
        cardSetName = Judgment;
        colors =         (
            green,
            white
        );
        convertedManaCost = 7;
        description = "Trample\nPhantom Nishoba enters the battlefield with seven +1/+1 counters on it.\nWhenever Phantom Nishoba deals damage, you gain that much life.\nIf damage would be dealt to Phantom Nishoba, prevent that damage. Remove a +1/+1 counter from Phantom Nishoba.";
        flavor = "";
        formats =         (
                        {
                legality = Legal;
                name = "Odyssey Block";
            },
                        {
                legality = Legal;
                name = Legacy;
            },
                        {
                legality = Legal;
                name = Vintage;
            },
                        {
                legality = Legal;
                name = Freeform;
            },
                        {
                legal`

I tried this sample of code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

var data:NSMutableData!
var arrvehicls:NSMutableArray!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.data = NSMutableData()
    self.arrvehicls = NSMutableArray()

    self.startConnection()
}

func startConnection(){
    let urlPath: String = "http://api.mtgdb.info/search/omni"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray

    for var i = 0; i<jsonResult.count; ++i {

        var dictResult = jsonResult.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary

        var vehicleInfo = Vehicle()
        vehicleInfo.id = dictResult.valueForKey("id") as! Int
        vehicleInfo.artist = dictResult.valueForKey("artist") as! String
        vehicleInfo.cardID = dictResult.valueForKey("cardSetId") as! String
        vehicleInfo.cardName = dictResult.valueForKey("cardSetName") as! String
        vehicleInfo.colors = dictResult.valueForKey("colors") as! NSArray
        vehicleInfo.details = dictResult.valueForKey("description") as! String
        vehicleInfo.flavour = dictResult.valueForKey("flavor") as! String
        vehicleInfo.formats = NSMutableArray()
        var arr = dictResult.valueForKey("formats") as! NSArray

        for var j = 0; j<arr.count; ++i {

            var dictFormats = arr.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary
            var formats = Formats()
            formats.legality = dictFormats.valueForKey("legality") as! String
            formats.name = dictFormats.valueForKey("name") as! String
            vehicleInfo.formats.addObject(formats)
        }
        self.arrvehicls.addObject(vehicleInfo)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know, even I confused how this was happened. :(